# Looking for ASL letter and gesture resources (images/datasets)

Tags: usa, images

I'm planning on working on a project at an upcoming event. I want to translate sign language (ASL) on the fly/teach a computer to translate ASL. I have a cousin who has taken a few ASL classes so I'll have him help verify, but are there any resources for images/gifs/videos of letters and common gestures?

I would be attaching a camera to record the user signing and then translate it.

Comment: So are you wanting to translate the ASL to voice ? Do you mean you want the video to include subtitles ?

Comment: @PROBERT I want to teach a computer recognize ASL, initially I'll work on just getting the letters recognized and displayed back to the user.i think the subtitles would help for my initial understanding, but I'm more in need of images than videos.